# After calling sql adapter procedure through javascript function in worklight-->how to make use of the invocation data?

Tags: worklight-adapters

I called the adapter procedure through the JavaScript function and it worked correctly. Now I'm stuck with how to make use of the invocation data from the database.

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
function aaa()
{
var x=document.getElementById("email").value;

var y=document.getElementById("mobile").value;

try{

WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
adapter : 'DB2',
procedure : 'procedure1',
parameters : [x,y]
}, {     onSuccess : function(result)

alert("login Success");  
},
onFailure : function(result){alert("login Failure");}
}); 
} 
catch(e)
{
alert("ERROR::"+e);
}

}

/* Below is my adapter.js file */

var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from user where           email=? and contact=?");

function procedure1(x,y) { 

return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
parameters : [x,y]
});

}

/*
Ignore the html tags. Now how do I make use of the result
(i.e.data returned after execution of query?)
*/

</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the onSuccess callback function in your WL.Client.invokeProcedure call:

```
onSuccess : function(result)
    alert("login Success");  
}
```

This function well receive the result returned from your adapter call. Change the method to this:

```
onSuccess : function(result)
    console.log(result);  
}
```

And then view the call in your browser. You will be able to see the structure of the returned data. Then its up to you on what to do with it.